# How to generate database weights?

Tags: benchmarking, weight, database

As a chain grows the DB operations should get costlier. Is there a standard procedure that outlines how to generate these weights? Or should we continue using the default substrate weights for this which may look like :

```rs
pub const RocksDbWeight: RuntimeDbWeight = RuntimeDbWeight {
            read: 25_000 * constants::WEIGHT_REF_TIME_PER_NANOS,
            write: 100_000 * constants::WEIGHT_REF_TIME_PER_NANOS,
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed advised to regularly update the database weights. You can see the result of this for example in the [Polkadot runtime](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/c2efce0d60d656cb13f5ade52bf3d866e17085fa/runtime/polkadot/constants/src/weights/paritydb_weights.rs#L60). The procedure is outlined in this [README](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/utils/frame/benchmarking-cli/src/storage/README.md). Please open an issue in Subustrate if the documentation is insufficient to produce usable results.